# Potential Dangers of ALIASing a Unix Command Starting with "."?

Tags: unix, shell, command-line, ksh

I'd like to use alias to make some commands for myself when searching through directories for code files, but I'm a little nervous because they start with ".". Here's some examples:

`$ alias .cpps="ls -a *.cpp"`

`$ alias .hs="ls -a *.h"`

Should I be worried about encountering any difficulties? Has anyone else done this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues with '.', but generally speaking many people discourage the use of aliases at all and recommend proper shell functions.  (eg .cpps() {ls -a *.cpp})

Comment: That actually makes a lot more sense. I'd love to know how the priority between commands in /usr/bin vs aliases vs shell functions lays out. Hmm..... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @daveslab: The builtin command `type` will tell you which is being called.

Comment: @Daveslab: you ask about how aliases compare to commands found on the PATH and so on.  For that, you need to read the manual.  AFAIK, aliases are searched first; if no alias is found, then it looks at built-ins, then at commands on the PATH.  But I stand to be corrected on how the built-ins fit into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the advantage of putting the dot in the names?  It seems like an unnecessary extra character.  I'd just use the base names (`hs` and `cpps`) for the aliases.

I suppose that it might be argued that the dot indicates that the command is an alias - but why is that distinction beneficial?  One of the great things about Unix was that it removed the distinction between hallowed commands provided by the O/S and programs written by the user.  They are all equal - just located in different places.

I don't see any real dangers with using aliases that start with a dot.  It would never have occurred to me to try; I'm mildly surprised that they are allowed.  But given that they are allowed, there is no real risk involved that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use '.' to begin your aliases because it's next to '/' and you could hit the two together by mistake and accidentally run an executable in your current directory (especially if you use tab completion).

Comment: What is the likelihood of their being a command `./cpps` in the current directory - that does any damage?   I don't think I've fumble-fingered the dot and slash keys - I mistype plenty of things, but don't recall that being a problem.

Comment: If you're compiling executables then there may well be something that starts with a 'c' in the current working directory. I think as a general rule that if you can type faster than your terminal displays (e.g. using a laggy SSH connection) and use tab completion e.g. ./c <tab> <enter> that would be a _potential_ danger. I don't know many people who spend time in shells who don't have a horror story to share about when they made a typo or used ^substitution^mistake and wreaked merry hell.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there's any technical problem though it's likely to be confusing to anyone who has used Unix for a long time. In my world commands don't have dots in them and file names don't have spaces or upper case letters!